# Xdebug with Netbeans 8.0 and xampp 1.8.3

Tags: php, windows, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

i installed the latest version of Xdebug according via the wizard for the xdebug.org site (http://xdebug.org/wizard.php). Xdebug is working according to phpinfo(). The HMTL output in my browser (Firefox 28) shows xdebug code. But Xdegub not communicate with Netbeans. In Netbeans compare the message "waiting for connection xampp netbeans-xdebug". I do not understand where the problem is.

I am using the following software:

```
Windows 8.1
Netbeans IDE 8.0
XAMPP Version 1.8.3
Xdebug 2.2.4
```

this is the configuration of my php.ini

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.4-5.5-vc11.dll
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
;xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
;xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
;xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
;xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
```

and this is to Netbeans

```
Debbuger Port: 9000
Session ID: netbeans-xdebug
http://oi57.tinypic.com/29gbqrk.jpg
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with localhost in `php.ini`.

Try this (use your real Network-IP-Address):

```
;xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_host = "192.168.1.106"
```